# Why News API not showing anything on HTML page but returns data on console.log

Tags: angular, api, angular-components

I Suspect the for loop might be taking time to display maybe? not really sure why this is not displaying

This is *news.component.html*

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles">
    <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{article.description}}</p>
    <a href="{{article.url}}">Read full article</a>
</div>
```

this is data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  apiKey = 'xxx';
  get(){
    return this.httpClient.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=${this.apiKey}`);
    
  }
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
}
```

this is news.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.css']
})
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {

  articles:any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.dataService.get().subscribe((data:any)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.articles = data['Articles'];  
    })
  }

}
```

expecting data to show on html component but it shows blank
Currently it's showing on console.log(data)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Do not publish any **API Keys**!
Then: your problem is a little typo.

```
this.articles = data['articles'];
```

**articles** with lower case. And it will working.

Comment: Thanks much, it worked! this is my first time working on APIs just trying something out but thanks!!

Comment: No problem. Is all fine you can vote up my post and set it "as answer", too. Thx very much.